# Update State column in a csv to display IL instead of Illinois in Python - Data Quality

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have a CSV file with State column, majority of the records have state as 2 characters (IL,CA,AZ) but there are few records that I need to clean up which spells the name of the state (Illinois, California, Arizona). Can anyone please suggest the code to clean up these states. For now, I can hard code only Illinois, but any advise on re-usability of the code to fix all the states in the USA to 2 char. Please advise.

This is the error I get while running a vsc file which has ~40k records:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4563: character maps to <undefined>
```

````
import geocoder
import unicodecsv
import logging
import time
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
pcode=[]
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
with open('Bookings.csv') as f:
     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
     for line in reader:
         if line['state'] == "Illinois":
            line['state'] = "IL"
f.to_csv("New_Bookings.csv", index=False)```
````

Comment: Can you read the all files first, then change the state name before you save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x9d` in UTF-8 would be a continuation byte attached to the preceding character.  If the preceding byte was below `0x7f`, then it would not be valid UTF-8.  `0x9d` is not a valid character in a Windows style encoding like ISO-8859-1 where each character is a single byte.  This leads me to believe that the file is in fact UTF-8.

`unicodecsv` requires a bytestream to process: So add the `b` flag for this as well as `r` because you only want to read:

```
with open('Bookings.csv', 'rb') as f:
```

Also, specify the encoding on the reader as well:

```
csv.DictReader(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

The data you are changing is not staying in memory.  It is only processing one line at a time.  So in order to write the new file, you must open a `csv writer` to write each line within the loop.  So something like this:

```
with open('Bookings.csv', 'rb') as f:
     reader = csv.DictReader(f, encoding='utf-8')
     with open(file_name, 'wb') as f_out:
         writer = csv.writer(f_out, encoding='utf-8')
         for line in reader:
             if line['state'] == "Illinois":
                line['state'] = "IL"
             writer.writerow(line)
```

Edit: So I was looking through some of the more common UTF-8 characters and found only one that contained `0x9d` (that's `0xe2 0x80 0x9d` to be exact).    It is the special closing double quote.  Open the file and search for this `”` to verify...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to build a dictionary in such format:

```
states = {
   "Illinois": "IL",
   "IL": "IL"
}
```

And then instead of bunch of If's statements just write:

```
line['state'] = states[line['state']]
```

Or in order to avoid redundant entries like "IL": "IL" you could check if length of line['state'] is greater than 2.

There is actually python [package](https://pypi.org/project/us/), that could be helpfull, but using it I think would be an overkill.